# No connection could be made because the target machine actively

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed lamp on **linux server 14.0.4**, I did not have phpmyadmin there, then I installed **phpmyadmin** on that server and when I ping on browser like *192.xxx.xx.200/phpmyadmin* it opens and brings me the databases.

But when I tried to connect from another system like 
`mysqli_connect('192.xxx.xx.xx','root','xxxx','xxxx')`

It gives me the error

> mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying to connect via tcp://192.xxx.xx.200:3306)

I have searched with Google, but i could not find the solution, but when i tried with the same system like *localhost* or *ip/phpmyadmin* it works fine.

Comment: Do you have any firewall active?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL maintains access credentials (usernames / passwords) by machine address as well as username. A new LAMP installation typically doesn't allow anything except local access.

If you issue a command series like this from your local machine you'll get remote access for `username` from all machines with addresses `192.168.*.*`.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'192.168.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL  ON * TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

PhpMyAdmin has a UI for this.

You can also `CREATE USER 'username'@'%'` to allow anyone from any machine anywhere to access your server. If you think that's a good idea, go for it. But be careful.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, i have tried with one created user except root , even it did not allow to access, then i have changed the bind-address = 192.168.xx.xx(ie system ip) on config file, now it works well, it is due to mysql protection.